# Create_Index using partialFilterExpression in python

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, pymongo-3.x

I am using below code to create a partial index in mongodb for the records having null values.
When I execute the below code.

```
    db = self.db_conn[db_name ]
    collection = db[collection_name]
    status = collection.create_index([("Col1", pym.ASCENDING), ("Col2", pym.ASCENDING)], {partialFilterExpression : {"value": None}})
```

Its giving me a error:

```
 "name 'partialFilterExpression' is not defined"
```

My 
pymongo version 3.2.2
Mongodb version 3.4

Answer (score 6):

Never mind Thanks for look into my post.
I found it

```
    status = collection.create_index([("Col1", pym.ASCENDING), ("col2", pym.ASCENDING)], partialFilterExpression = {"Values": None}, background = True)
```

It should be "=" instead of ":"